# Problem regarding single output by printf() function of format printf("format specifier",variable,"format specifier",variable); in C

Tags: c

I have just started C basics by learning from the book Programming by ANSI C 8th Edition and encountered a simple program of adding two numbers.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int number;
    float amount;
    number=100;
    amount=20.11+30.75;
    printf("%d\n",number);
    printf("%5.2f",amount);
}
```

So after trying the above code ,I tried to run it by writing like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int number;
    float amount;
    number=100;
    amount=20.11+30.75;
    printf("%d\n",number,"%5.2f",amount);
}
```

I was expecting an output that appeared in the former code which was

100
50.86

But I got an output of 100 only. Why the amount(50.86) wasn't present in the output?

Comment: Look at the man page for `printf`.  The first argument is a format string, and the rest are arguments to the format strings.  You can't supply multiple format string.  How would it even know when to stop looking?  It's doesn't know how many arguments were passed.  All it knows is that the format string must be present as the first argument.  Everything else it knows comes from the format string.

Comment: And in any case, there's no need for multiple format strings.  Just combine them, and move the other arguments to the end.

Comment: The first parameter to `printf` is the format string. You need to specify everything you want to output in that. What you've asked it to do is print an integer followed by a newline where the next parameter is the integer to print. The rest of the parameters are ignored. What you probably want is something like `printf("%d, %5.2f\n", number, amount);`

Comment: You can't just randomly throw things together and expect it to work.

Answer (score 2):

> Why the amount(50.86) wasn't present in the output?

Because the *format* only needed 1 following parameter.

---

`printf()`'s first parameter is a *format*, a pointer to a *string*.  The format is parsed and uses the remaining augments *as needed*.

```
printf("%d\n", number,...);
```

Since parsing `"%d\n"` resulted in reading only 1 following parameter with the `int` value `100`, the output was

```
"100\n"
```

Extra arguments are not used by `printf()`.  The below 3 print the same output.

```
// Same output
printf("%d\n",number,"%5.2f",amount);       
printf("%d\n",number,);       
printf("%d\n",number,123.0, 42, "hello World");
```

---

To print `number` and `amount`:

```
// printf("%d\n",number,"%5.2f",amount);
printf("%d\n%5.2f", number, amount);
// or better as 
printf("%d %5.2f\n", number, amount);
```

---

Aside: avoid `float` unless truly needed.  `20.11 + 30.75` is an addition of 2 `double`.

```
float amount = 20.11 + 30.75;
```

If `amount` is to represent money 1) Definitely do not use `float` and 2) be aware of the non-decimal binary nature of floating point  types.

Consider counting *cents*, not *dollars*.

Recommend starting out with `long long` count of cents.